# Unicorn before_fork and after_fork for Sidekiq+Redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, redis, unicorn, sidekiq

In unicorn.conf, `preload_app` is supposed to be set true for performance, but requires starting and stopping Redis in the fork callback. [The example here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-optimize-unicorn-workers-in-a-ruby-on-rails-app) refers to Resque, but I'm wondering what the best setup is for Sidekiq AND where I want to use Redis for other purposes, ie as a persistent database.

I found [some info](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/120), but nothing specifically on the best practice for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using redis-rb, it connects on demand, so the master never opens a socket. Which means that you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Connection is opened in demand with the use of the method ensure_connected in the redis-rb library, however, it does not mean you do not need to disconnect or at least to open a new connection in any new worker. Otherwise, you will end having many workers sharing the same file descriptor and connection, which can cause problems with the concurrency.

Please see the redis-rb unicorn [example](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/3.1/examples/unicorn/unicorn.rb). In different versions you can see that connect or disconnect are used, both are valid.